# I cannot understand a react error message

Tags: reactjs, axios

I keep getting this error on react

./src/actions/index.js
Module not found: `C:\Projects\loginMaster\loginBoilerPlate\node_modules\axios\index.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `LoginBoilerPlate`.

I cannot seem to understand it. I have reinstalled axios with npm several times, I have removed the node modules and run npm install again. What does it mean?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: It can be a problem with `webpack`. I've noticed that your working directory path contains `loginBoilerPlate` and the error mentions the `LoginBoilerPlate` path. Feel the difference? Try using `case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin`

Comment: am using create-react-app @RohithMurali

Comment: When did you start seeing this issue? Did you rename the folder?

Comment: Best is to start a new project with create-react-app, then start copying the code from the project you see problems in. Do it gradually, until you get the error. Try to find why the last step caused the error, or write here what you did when the error appeared.